# use array as a public array to save random number generation

Tags: android, arrays, random

I want to generate random number without duplicate, and i get this code

```
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();   
    int random = randomGenerator.nextInt(16)+1;
    if (!numbers.contains(random))
    {
        numbers.add(random);
    }
```

I want to use this code to generate an random id to choose which question to be displayed from database. When i answer the question, it should be generate a new random id. But if I used all the code above, the array becomes a new one, and it will not know what id has been generated before.

If I put the `ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();` on `onCreate` and the other codes in a `public int random()`, the `numbers` in cannot read the array that i have created on `onCreate`.

I want to ask, can I create the `ArrayList<Integer>` as a public array, so i just should declare it once on `onCreate` method and the whole class can use this array.

Comment: Yes you can, why are you asking?

Comment: how? when i use the ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(); in onCreate and i want to use the array from another void, it said that numbers cannot be resolved.. How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare the ArrayList outside the onCreate method and initialize it inside that method.
Then happily use it in your activity.

So, this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

goes UP in your code, after the class declaration (after the first `{` in your class)

and this:

```
Random randomGenerator = new Random();   
int random = randomGenerator.nextInt(16)+1;
if (!numbers.contains(random))
{
    numbers.add(random);
}
```

Can be put in your onCreate method

Answer (score 0):

Declare your array separately from the handling it, for instance as the global class one.

```
public class ClassName {
   ArrayList<Integer> name;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(...){
      name = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   }

   public void yourMethod(...){
      //your operations
   }
}
```

In that way you can keep your array. I wouldn't create a public array, because if you define it as global and private, you have an access to it from the whole class. If you want to get access from other classes in a package, just create usual method:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> getArrayList(){
   return name;
}
```

btw, I'd use `Set<Integer>` [(here are docs)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) to solve that problem, because it doesn't allow you add duplicated items, so you may get rid of redundant if statement.

Comment: how does "Set" mean? :D

Comment: I've made an edition, also - [refer to docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html).